# How to fix this undefined index error? Ajax to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, database

> **Notice**: Undefined index: query in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Java\Search\instant-search.php** on line **71**
>   {"names":[]}

This is my Php

```php
$query=$_POST["query"];
$matchType=isset($_POST["match_type"])? $_POST["match_type"]:MatchType::CONTAINS;

processRequest($query,$matchType);
```

Here is my ajax script

```js
$("#query").keyup(function(){
    var q=$(this).val();
    var match_type=$("input[type=radio]:checked").val();
    var data={'query':q,'match_type':match_type};
    if(q.length==0){
        $("#results").html("");
        return false;

        $.ajax({
            url:"/Java/Search/instant-search.php",
            data:data,
            type:"post",
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(res)  {
                var tmpl=$("#names_tmpl").html();
                var html=Mustache.to_html(tmpl,res);

                $("#results").html(html);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO if you want to add code use `{}` button or indent code with 4 spaces, use snippets only if you want to add code that can be run in the browser.

Comment: Are you sure that `q` and `match_type` are defiend? try to run `console.log(data)`

Comment: First of all check either getting values or not..`console.log(q);` and console.log(match_type); than use data as `data="query="+q+"&match_type="+match_type,`

Comment: Yes, i did that already. I'm sorry, i'm just beginning to learn jquery. Both of them are getting values

Comment: And did u get values in both `console.log(q);` and `console.log(match_type);`

Comment: are you sure those are the relevant PHP lines? at least the `$matchType=...` line shouldn't throw that notice due to the `isset` guard

Comment: Check if you're not editing wrong file.

Comment: @jcubic I think file is fine that's y OP getting undefined ..

Comment: Should i post the whole code?

Comment: i'm copying his code https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kN3IT_qYXus

Comment: Did you try uppercase POST?

Comment: I tried, the problem remain

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments if both of them   `match_type` and `q` are getting values than use ajax with `data` as:

```
$.ajax({ 
   url:"/Java/Search/instant-search.php", 
   data: "query="+q+"&match_type="+match_type , 
   type:"post", 
   dataType:"json", 
   success:function(res) { 
     var tmpl=$("#names_tmpl").html(); 
     var html=Mustache.to_html(tmpl,res);
     $("#results").html(html); 
   } 
});
```

Comment: still not working, im guessing maybe its the connection, do i have to change something to my url or my php file ?

Comment: @shiroo before change test other answer as well. Maybe change. Type to method will work.

Comment: @shiroo: use `isset()` for both `$query=isset($_POST["query"]) ? $_POST["query"] : "";` same for other field

Comment: @shiroo still looking for answer?

Answer (score 0):

To change the type of request use `method` property not `type` and use Uppercase string `POST` [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
   $.ajax({
        url: "/Java/Search/instant-search.php",
        data: data,
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(res) {
            var tmpl=$("#names_tmpl").html();
            var html=Mustache.to_html(tmpl,res);

            $("#results").html(html);       
        }
    });
```

Comment: Still undefined index

Comment: @Shiroo Are you inspecting the response in developer tools?

Comment: according to the linked docu: - type is an alias of method and should be fine at the moment. - type takes its paramater in uppercase, so it should be `type or method: 'POST'`. with wrong paramters it will fall back to `GET`

Comment: @cypherabe.. Not agreed friend do u have any resource?

Comment: @devpro that's what I read in the linked api description (this (jcubic's ) answer). did I interpret that wrong?